# Timer display counts days instead of seconds

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a strange issue with a basic timer on my ms-access 2010 database. When the timer runs instead of increasing the seconds on the display box it increases days.

I've tried changing the formats around but the issue persists so I think it must be an issue with my code.

Here's my timer setup:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Dim blnNewRecord As Boolean
Dim dteStartTime As Date

Sub Form_Timer()
'Timer interval set to 1000 in form settings
Me.Timer_Display = DateDiff("s", dteStartTime, Now())
End Sub

Private Sub StartWork_Click()
'Do stuff
dteStartTime = Now()
End Sub
```

This works in that the timer display updates every second, but instead of ticking up in seconds (00:00:00 to 00:00:01 for example) It ticks up like this: 01/01/1900 00:00:00 -> 02/01/1900 00:00:00 every second. The format of the text box is set to Long time.

Any idea on what's causing this?

Comment: I suspect you are converting the number of seconds to date (in the text box format perhaps?) again. A date in VBA is stored a the number of days since January 1st 1900.

Comment: @CreeXLR maybe your text box must be set as **Long** , I don't know what is  **Long Time** maybe its the same, else if its not working I can propose an answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change format of textbox to Numeric.
This is because `DateDiff("s", dteStartTime, Now())` will return number of seconds. And `Long time` format makes textbox think this is `Date` which is stored as `Double`. So number of seconds becames number of days since 1/1/1900.

**UPDATE**: if you need `Long time` format 00:00:02 just change assignment to

```vba
Me.Timer_Display = Now() - dteStartTime
```

Comment: Brilliant! That solved it! Before seeing your update I was also going to try Me.Timer_Display = Format((Now() - dteStartTime), "hh:mm:ss") but your solution is more elegant. Thank you!